# unable to use HDD disk drive

Tags: ssd, ram, external-hdd

I have two disk SSD (128GB) and HDD (1TB) i used to install windows on SSD and I had kept my files on HDD but recently i've installed Linux on my SSD. Now I can't use my HDD drive anymore. problem is that I can only **read** files but delete or changing is unable so how can i use my HDD like additional drive (read/write/delete) ? i'm so tired pleas help me !!!

Comment: Do you still have Windows in your SSD? If so, boot into windows and disable "fast boot". Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: no i have deleted windows and installed ubuntu 22.04

Comment: i wanna use my SSD for linux OS and HDD for file storage. can i do this ?

Comment: Windows have "fast boot" enabled by default. This means when you shutdown Windows it essentially hibernates and keeps the HDD in "dirty" mode. The question I have linked above has duplicate two links and many solutions in those links. Some of them are quite old. Some require booting windows. Ubuntu 22.04 uses a newer driver for NTFS partitions and some of the old solutions may not work out of the box. One solution is to copy all the data to an external drive and format the HDD to ext4 instead of NTFS.

Comment: Feel free to **Answer Your Own Question** if you find a new solution using the builtin tools of Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: thank you I'll try and If i'm not mistalken, I copy my files and format my HDD and then can i write any files to it ?

Comment: Yes. As long as you have copied all your files to another SSD/HDD. Formatting the internal HDD should solve the problem. You can use the apps Disks or Gparted in Ubuntu to format your HDD. I recommend you select the `ext4` format instead of NTFS or something else, as this is the default used by Ubuntu. One more thing. Don't format the wrong partition!